# Instantiating interfaces in Java/Kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin

I read that in Java "interfaces cannot be instantiated - they can only be implemented by classes or extended by other interfaces".

However I can perfectly write:

```
val set = setOf<String>("one", "two")
```

in Kotlin, with `set` being of type `Set<String>`.

Doesn't this contradict my first statement as I'm instantiating the `Set`?

Comment: The function returns an object of type `Set<T>`, but the actual type of the object is from a class that implements `Set<T>`, such as `HashSet` or something else.

Comment: This makes your code independent of the actual `Set` implementation, which gives `setOf` the power to, for example, give different implementation depending on the parameters. Two common ones are to return a special empty set, or a special set with only one element for performance reasons. Also, the Kotlin standard library could change the set implementation later without breaking user code.

Comment: Tip: if you ctrl-click or Cmd-click on `setOf()`, you'll navigate to the implementation of the function, allowing to understand what it does.

Comment: @JBNizet: Seeing the implementation can be useful, but it can also be dangerous, as implementations can change, and shouldn't be relied on.  In particular, I think there's been talk of `arrayOf()` and/or `setOf()` returning new, specialised classes for small collections.

Comment: @gidds I'm not encouraging the OP to rely on the specific implementation of setOf(). I'm encouraging hm/her to look at the code to be able to answer his/her own question, and learn about OO.

Answer (score 0):

> I read that in Java "interfaces cannot be instantiated - they can only be implemented by classes or extended by other interfaces"

What this means is just that you can't write

```
Set<String> set = new Set<String>(...);
```

(don't confuse with `new Set<String> { ... }` which creates an anonymous class implementing `Set` and instantiates *that class*). You *can* write [`Set.of("one", "two")`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#of(E,%20E)) though this method was only added in Java 9. It is a factory method, just like Kotlin `setOf`, not "instantiating an interface".

The Kotlin equivalent to the illegal `new Set` would be

```
val set = Set<String>(...)
```

which is also not allowed.

Though Kotlin intentionally blurs the line between constructors and methods; it would be perfectly in line with other types in the standard library to define a factory method called `Set` which would be called in the same way, or an `operator fun invoke` in the companion object. See the [`List` method](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-list.html) for an example.